# error: (-217:Gpu API call) no kernel image is available for execution on the device in function 'split'

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorrt

I use opencv with CUDA TensorRT inside ubuntu docker. when i run my code i receive error below

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
> recognation0  |   what():  OpenCV(4.5.2) /home/opencv_contrib-4.5.2/modules/cudev/include/opencv2/cudev/grid/detail/split_merge.hpp:241: error: (-217:Gpu API call) no kernel image is available for execution on the device in function 'split'

Comment: The version of tensortrt or opencv hasn’t been built with support for your gpu

Comment: [crosspost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266159): https://forum.opencv.org/t/no-kernel-image-is-available-for-execution-on-the-device-in-function-split/12699

Answer (score 0):

Solution!

-D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=8.0

> https://forum.opencv.org/t/no-kernel-image-is-available-for-execution-on-the-device-in-function-split/12699